# create object in n1ql

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have some nested queries that returns me an array of objects, each object has 5 properties: id, value1, value2, attr1, attr2
in the array there could be multiple docs (obj) for a specific id.

meaning I have multiple ids, and for each id multiples attr1 and attr2 (each attr1, attr2 combination is an object in the array I currently have).

I want to create an object that looks like that:

```
    id: {
          attr1: {
                  attr2: {value1, value2}
               }
        }
}
```

any way to do that? 
tried to search for various of object/array function but couldn't find anything that can help me.

Answer (score 1):

This is rather simple, you just have to use arrays instead. Here is a more complete example:

```
INSERT INTO `test` ( KEY, VALUE ) VALUES ( "1", {
  "type": "users",
  "name": "First User",
  "username": "user1",
  "address": {
    "streetName": "Wayside Lane", 
      "houseNumber": 3104, 
        "zipcode": 94538, 
        "city": "Fremont", 
        "state": "CA", 
        "country": "US", 
        "entrances": [{"name" : "main"}] },
  "preferences": [
    {"name": "lang", "value": "en"},
    {"name": "notification", "value":"emailOnly"},
    {"name":"timezone","value": "GMT+2"}],
  "permissions": {
    "groups":["MARKETING"], 
    "roles": ["ADMIN", "PREMIUM_USER"]}
});
```

Note that you could have as much nested entities as you want, although it is recommended to have a max depth of 2 or 5 entities.

Comment: the thing is I don't know the keys or values, they are returned from a query and I have multiple objects in the array I get from the query which are unsorted. how can I push it to an object? loop and condition to check if it exists or not?
I also don't want to write it to the db, just get it as a result of a query, how can I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Are the keys dynamic?

Comment: Yes, if you will take a look at my example again then attr1 and attr2 are dynamic.